# XWiki ignores global edit rights for XWikiAllGroup

Tags: user-management, rights, xwiki

We are using XWiki in Version 4.5 and I want to set edit-rights by default for every user. But setting edit-rights on XWikiAllGroup globaly via the administration-panel doesn't take effect. I still need to add edit-rights explicitly on every space. Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding anything in XWikis rights-management?

Thx!

Hein

Answer (score 0):

When ever you create any space in xwiki you need to set write permission for different groups. 
Here are a few things about permissions in xwiki I would like to tell you..
1> whenever a user login for first time he moves into XWikiAllGroup because this group has by default privilege of registering a user which you can remove and give to other group.

2> you can create a group of your own and give permissions to user as per your req. which is the best part of it. You need to go to space and set the group permissions.

Always keep a user in a single group to avoid any complication.